# podfile setup when one project is dependent on other

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, podfile

Consider this as my podfile

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '11.0'
workspace 'ClientMobile.xcworkspace'


target 'Sdk' do
  project 'ios-sdk/sdk.xcodeproj'
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => false
  )
end


target 'lib' do 
    project 'ios-lib/lib.xcodeproj'
end

target 'ClientMobile' do
  config = use_native_modules!
  # Pods for ClientMobile
end

post_install do |installer|
  react_native_post_install(installer)
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
      end
  end
end
```

Here we have 3 projects.

1. Sdk (Framework Project)
2. lib
3. App (ClientMobile)

My Sdk is dependent on Lib and my App is dependent on  SDK.

How would I structure it so that I can work smoothly in development.

Currently, I follow this flow.

1. I have created a podspec file for my `lib` which I refer in my sdk

```
    target 'Sdk' do
      project 'ios-sdk/sdk.xcodeproj'
      config = use_native_modules!
      pod 'react-native-mobile' , :path => "./../mobile-example.podspec"
      use_react_native!(
        :path => config[:reactNativePath],
        # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
        :hermes_enabled => false
      )
    end
```

and then I build my sdk, have a podspec file to use output folder as a pod and then do pod install.

I am confident that this is the most in-efficient way of doing it because

1. if I add a file in `lib` then to use it in my `sdk` I need to do pod install again
2. I need to create framework and then do pod install

Can someone help me in making this process smooth for development?